# Kendo Grid Filtering a dataSource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a grid bound to a simple object. There are no Ajax calls. It's all set at init.

My Object: **Account** with properties **Name** and an **Array** of **Tag** strings. Real simple.

I pass in an array of tags into this function and need the dataSource to filter the grid. How is that done?

```
function filterGridResults(tags) {
  var grid = $("#gridAccounts").data("kendoGrid");
  var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
  //??? filter document.Tags
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are binding your grid to local data.  If so then this should solve your problem:

```
function filterGridResults(tags) {
    var grid = $("#gridAccounts").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataSource = grid.dataSource;

    var filterField = "Tag";//This is the object field you will filter by
    var filterOperator = "contains";//How you will filter
    var filterValue = tags;//What your filter value will be

    dataSource.filter(
        {
            field: filterField, 
            operator: filterOperator , 
            value: filterValue 
        });
}
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Just noticed you had an array, basically you pass multiple objects into the `dataSource.filter` method separated by commas.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to handle the search when the databound object's property is an Array too? SOmething like a Array-Contains like search?

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com do you want to filter for tags that have ANY of the values in the array or filter for objects that contain EVERY value in the array? Basically && or ||?